# how to clean jacoco.exec after running integration tests in a multi-module project

Tags: sonarqube

I have a multimodule Maven project, it is analyzed using the Sonar Maven runner and coverage is done with Jacoco. For our integration tests we want to see the coverage *across* all modules (because they are integration tests after all).
Therefore we configure the jacoco-it.exec file to be in `${user.dir}`, with the `append`property to true. This way all modules append their information to the same location and coverage is calculated over all modules.

But since `append` is true the file will still be there on a next run, since it isn't placed in a directory that maven cleans. This leads to incorrect coverage reports.

What is the best way to clean up this file after a sonar run? Ideally I would like to configure this in the same pom profile as our jacoco/sonar configuration, so that no other projects need to remember to set a clean step in Jenkins or whereever. The sonar/jacoco configuration is in a company wide parent pom file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Maven, you could try and use the [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to delete the file.

I don't know how you run Sonar Maven, but you can either bind the maven-antrun-plugin task to a phase after the one the Sonar Maven Runner is bound to (and you would have the file deleted automatically and the end of each run) or you can call the maven-antrun-plugin from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I eventually resorted to using the exec plugin: `mvn clean install; mvn sonar:sonar exec:exec`. But that is platform dependend and I couldn't find a way to bind it some phase, imho you can't bind a mojo to a phase? So how could I bind the antrun to a phase?

Comment: imho you can't bind to a phase because that will always be executed after each module, and in this use case you'd only want the file to be removed after all modules have run